# Is kafka stream library dependent on underlying kafka broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to use feature from kafka stream 2.2 library ,however, my underlying kafka broker version is not 2.2.

Is it possible to use kafka stream 2.2 version of library against kafka broker 2.12-1.1.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use kafka stream 2.2 version of library against kafka broker 2.12-1.1.1 ?

Yes, this is possible. Kafka Streams is forward-compatible and backward-compatible to Kafka clusters. For example, you can also use older Kafka Streams versions with newer Kafka clusters, for what it's worth. This means you can independently upgrade applications and clusters, which are often also managed by different teams (e.g. "the fraud team" is responsible for developing, upgrading, and running a KStreams application to detect fraudulent payments, and a separate Ops team is responsible for the Kafka clusters).

For full details see the version compatibility matrix at https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/introduction.html#ak. (There should be the same version matrix on the Apache Kafka website, but I couldn't find it right now.)

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer and link provided.